# How to make grouped request by only day part of created_at?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

In my my `laravel 5.7.3` application , I need to get grouped date like

```
$voteItemUsersResults = VoteItemUsersResult::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
             ->groupBy('created_at')
             ->having('created_at', '>', '2018-09-01')
             ->get();
```

but I need to get only day part of created_at, without time.

Which is the valid way to make it ?

Comment: For example, output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped by Only Day of Datetime .

```
$voteItemUsersResults = VoteItemUsersResult::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
             ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d")'))
             ->having('created_at', '>', '2018-09-01')
             ->get();
```